# Excel 2010: Concatenated URL broken when saved to PDF

Tags: excel, pdf, hyperlink, excel-2010

I have a small application built in Excel 2010 with cell functions plus some vba subs and a vba function that is called in worksheet cells.

One column has a formula in each cell that builds a hyperlink using a base URL, variable part, fixed part, variable part.

Works great, until...
I save the print area to PDF using the inbuilt functionality in Excel 2010.

The generated PDF shows hyperlinks that *look* OK but the link actually only takes you to the first part of the concatenated URL (the base URL).

Eg this link:
https://www.support.unisys.com/common/epa/macro.aspx?path0=a-s&path1=ple&path2=web-select&SELECT=PLE-PLE-TO-IC+eq+MCP-054.1A.117&TITLE=PLE(s)+released+since+IC:+MCP-054.1A.116

Would be generated by the following formula:
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://www.support.unisys.com/common/epa/macro.aspx?path0=a-s&path1=ple&path2=web-select&SELECT=PLE-PLE-TO-IC+eq+",D1,"&TITLE=PLE(s)+released+since+IC:+",C1))

The saved PDF displays the hyperlink label as:
https://www.support.unisys.com/common/epa/macro.aspx?path0=a-s&path1=ple&path2=web-select&SELECT=PLE-PLE-TO-IC+eq+MCP-054.1A.117&TITLE=PLE(s)+released+since+IC:+MCP-054.1A.116

But the actual link takes you to:
https://www.support.unisys.com/common/epa/macro.aspx?path0=a-s&path1=ple&path2=web-select&SELECT=PLE-PLE-TO-IC+eq+

Any ideas how to get it to create the correct hyperlink in the PDF? Or is this a Microsoft bug(or Adobe)?

Regards,
Graham

Comment: Are you sure Excel actually exports the URLs as active PDF components (annotations)? I ask because Adobe Reader has a feature that tries to recognize URLs in the plain text of a PDF, but that feature obviously stops at a line break.

Comment: I actually don't know (will need to research that). However it's strange that the displayed URL in the PDF is the full dynamically calculated URL, but the hyperlink takes you just to the base URL... Surely if it was as you say, the label would be truncated as well as the target?

Comment: Please provide a sample file for inspection.

Comment: Will do, on the road currently, will do this tomorrow when in the office.

Comment: Hmm, corporate web filter blocks "Online Storage" categorised sites, so can't just upload there and link in the post. Pity SO doesn't allow file uploads...

Comment: Should be easy to replicate from what I've posted though, surely? If not, I'll find a way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that I needed to select Ignore Print Areas on the PDF options dialog, to avoid lines being inserted during the conversion, because of the really long URL.

I also had to amend commas in the URL to be URL encoded (%2C) to truncation on the comma in the PDF.

See link below where I got the Ignore Print Areas nugget:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/excel-2010-concatenated-url-broken-when-saved-to/940ff1f5-fbdb-4875-a4f7-536b615e6df2